# Shaded jar ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.logging.java.JavaLoggingSystem

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, exception, integration-testing

I'm using Maven to create a **shaded** jar that's bootable. i.e. It comes packaged with all the required dependencies and should be executable using

> java -jar integration-tests.jar

But when I execute this code it produces the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.logging.java.JavaLoggingSystem
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:117)
    at com.ciscospark.integration.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:41)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.logging.java.JavaLoggingSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:125)
    ... 10 more
```

But the strange thing is that if I unzip integration-tests.jar I'll find

> **extracted**/BOOT-INF/libspring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar

within which I'll find

> ./org/springframework/boot/logging/java/JavaLoggingSystem.class

What am I doing wrong?

My Maven configuration

```
<build>
    <finalName>integration-tests</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.integration.JUnitTestRunner</mainClass>
                <finalName>integration-tests</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</testClassesDirectory>
                <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>standalone</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>${tomcat.server.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                        <cargo.rmi.port>${tomcat.rmi.port}</cargo.rmi.port>
                        <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>${tomcat.ajp.port}</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>com.me</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-server</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <properties>
                            <context>/</context>
                        </properties>
                        <pingUrlPath>/ping</pingUrlPath>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-server</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: seen [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/it-random-port.html) ?

Comment: I had not. Nice tip.

Comment: welcome..., but looks like spring-boot-maven-plugin is really overstrained by your (very special) need - if you're flexible, then use the plugin more in the "documented way", if not - somewhat agree with @Hitobat and `<mainClass>com.integration.JUnitTestRunner</mainClass>` is suspicious!

Answer (score 0):

I've only managed to get spring-boot-maven-plugin to work specifically when packaging an Application with all its dependencies. For anything else it doesn't seem to work.

My theory is that when you start a spring boot app the first thing it does is extract all the jars you need, but I've never bothered to look into it further.

To solve your problem, I recommend you look at using the maven-assembly-plugin instead to perform the fatjar package.

Comment: I'll look into maven-assembly-plugin